# date function not correctly returning date

Tags: php, wordpress

This code is being used to generate the date of a post in wordpress:

```
<span class="the_date">Posted: <?php echo get_the_time('F d, Y'); ?></span>
```

However it is not resutning the date, it is returning the text instead:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is Considering that you are using the `get_the_time()` within a WordPress loop, `print_r( $post )` & check what the `$post->post_date` property obtains to start with for each of the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try with the following formats

```
<?php  the_time('F j, Y \a\t g:i a');  ?> or

<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
```